# Problema con SearchView Actionbar Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Quiero ver si me pueden ayudar con otro problema, lo que pasa es que en mi `Activity` donde yo muestro Clientes en un `listView` personalizado, integre en la parte del `ActionBar` un `SearchView` para que los usuarios puedan Buscar el cliente, ya tengo integrad mi `SearchView` en mi Diseño y ya lo muestra solo cuando yo ejecuto la App, solo que cuando trato de buscar un cliente no hace la búsqueda

Código de mi Activity y mi layout

layout Menu

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Activity Metodo Oncreate Menu donde los Instanceo y uso

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_cliente, menu);

        final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        //permite modificar el hint que el EditText muestra por defecto
        searchView.setQueryHint(getText(R.string.search));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                    adaptador.filter("");
                    list.clearTextFilter();
                } else {
                    adaptador.filter(newText);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Codigo Activity parte donde esta mi adaptador personalizado

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor>{

        private List<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor> searchList;

        public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor> ArrayClientes)
        {
            super(context, 0, ArrayClientes);
            this.searchList = new ArrayList<>();
            this.searchList.addAll(cliArrayList);
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return cliArrayList.size();
        }



        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;

            CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor O_Cliente = getItem(position);

            // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_cliente, parent, false);
            }


            //Obteniendo instancias de los text views
            TextView nombre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nombrecli);
            TextView saldov = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtsaldov);
            TextView saldot = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtsaldot);
            TextView idcli = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.clienid);


            //INICIALIZAR FORMAT
            DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");

            nombre.setText(O_Cliente.getClienteDescripcion());
            nombre.setTag(O_Cliente);

            saldov.setText(numberFormat.format(O_Cliente.getSaldoVencido()));
            saldot.setText(numberFormat.format(O_Cliente.getSaldo()));

            idcli.setText(String.valueOf(O_Cliente.getCliente()));
            idcli.setTag(O_Cliente);

            // Se almacena en settag el objeto Cliente
            convertView.setTag(O_Cliente);

            //Devolver al ListView la fila creada
            return convertView;
        }

        public void filter(String newText) {
          /*  newText = newText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            cliArrayList.clear();
            if (newText.length() == 0) {
                cliArrayList.addAll(searchList);
            } else {
                for (CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor s : searchList) {
                    if (s.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(newText)) {
                        cliArrayList.add(s);
                    }
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();*/
        }
    }
```

Comment: Soy  muy novato en Android, diria que dentro de tu adaptador debes filtrar los datos, mirate ese enlace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769257/custom-listview-adapter-with-filter-android

Comment: si lo tengo un metodo de filtro.. pero no hace nada...

Comment: public void filter(String newText) {
           newText = newText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            cliArrayList.clear();
            if (newText.length() == 0) {
                cliArrayList.addAll(searchList);
            } else {
                for (CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor s : searchList) {
                    if (s.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(newText)) {
                        cliArrayList.add(s);
                    }
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

Comment: En los ejemplos extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable { y a dentro public EmployeeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Employee> employeeArrayList) aquí otro ejemplo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422072/searchview-in-listview-having-a-custom-adapter

Comment: ya lo cambien pero me arroja otros errores, tendria que cambiar mucho codigo,,, yo lo necesitaria usando arrayadapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al ingresar un texto este debe ser recibido por el método **`onQueryTextSubmit()`** :

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(final String query) {
  //Realiza proceso del Asynctask
  //Después de obtener los datos por medio del Asynctask actualizas tu adapter! 
  return true; 
}
```

Debes usar `onQueryTextSubmit` y no `onQueryTextChange`, esta es la diferencia entre ambos métodos:

> [**onQueryTextChange(String consulta)**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html#onQueryTextChange(java.lang.String)) Se llama cuando el texto de consulta
> es cambiado por el usuario.
>
> [**onQueryTextSubmit(String consulta)**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html#onQueryTextSubmit(java.lang.String)) Se llama
> cuando el usuario envía la consulta.

Comment: alguien que me pueda dar otra sugerencia de filtro de búsqueda para un listview y un arrayadapter

Comment: R.string.search de donde estoy obteniendo esta variable search.

Comment: @Jorgesys :D https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/88361/implemetar-un-searchview-en-actionbar-y-lista-personalizada-webservice

Comment: ayudame @Jorgesys ;c